# Having trouble finding where the error in my code is that is causing my code to give the wrong answer

Tags: java

My code is supposed to find the monthly payout of a loan. It does not give the right answer. I am in an intro to java course, and they want us to do it a certain way, so please leave everything the same except where I messed up.

We have to ask the user for their annual interest rate (not monthly), length of the loan, and the initial amount of cash

The equation is P = (r * L) / (1-(1+r)^-n)
where r is the monthly interest rate, L is the length of the loan, n is the number of months of the loan. P is the monthly payback of the loan

I've looked hard to find where my math is messed up, but I fear I have tunnel vision and cannot find where to correct it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaProgram {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("This program calculates your monthly payment");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print ("Please enter the loan amount:" );
        double loanAmount = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print ("Please enter the  annual interest amount as a percentage, e.g 0.055 for 5.5%:" );
        double annualInterest = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print ("Please enter the length of the loan payback:" );
        double lengthYears = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println ("Your monthly payback is" + 
        divisionPart(multiplicationPart(monthlyInterest(annualInterest), lengthYears), 
        secondPartOfEquation(monthlyInterest(annualInterest), yearsToMonths(lengthYears))));
    }

    public static double secondPartOfEquation(double x, double y) {
        double result = (1- Math.pow((1 + x), -y));
        return result;
    }

    public static double yearsToMonths(double x) {
        double result = (x * 12);
        return result;
    }    

    public static double multiplicationPart(double x, double y) {
        double result = (x * y);
        return result;
    }

    public static double divisionPart(double x, double y) {
        double result = (x / y);
        return result;
    }

    public static double monthlyInterest(double x) {
        double result = (x / 12);
        return result;
    }

}
```

> With the input of:
>   initial cash 10000, length 5 years, annual percentage 5.5% (0.055)
>   I should get 191.01, but get 0.09550581085891031.

Comment: The translation of the formula to java math seems sound to me. Except for one part. Are you sure the translation from yearly to monthly interest is simply about dividing the former by twelve ? Seems fishy.

Comment: Are you sure the monthly interest is simply the annual interest divided by 12? I would say the 12th-root (don't know how to write this in text)

Comment: @Sibuscus wrote: *"This is a classic problem solved by debugging. I always recommend learning how to debug before posting here. I promise you'll find the problem instantly. If I tell you what your problem was, you'll have learned nothing and post similar stuff again in the future"*. See also [Debug Strategy (for small programs)](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/debug/).

Comment: As far as I can see, you never use the variable `loanAmount` after it was initialized with a value that I suspect to be important for your calculation.